# Convert Spring xml configuration to Java configuration under Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to migrate existing application Spring security configuration written in XML to Java Configuration (with Spring Boot)

Can you please help as to how the Java config needs to be defined for the below xml. I keep getting confused looking at different webpages..
Thanks in advance!

```
<security:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="filterEntryPoint">
    <security:custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myWebAuthorizationFilter" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_EVP"/>
</security:http>

<bean id="filterEntryPoint" 
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl">
        <value>https://companyLogin.com</value>
    </property>
    <property name="forceHttps">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this part, you will need to define a custom filter

```
<security:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="filterEntryPoint">
    <security:custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myWebAuthorizationFilter" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_EVP"/>
</security:http>
```

such as

```
public class MyCustomFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter (ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

And then register the custom filter

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .addFilterBefore(new MyCustomFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') and hasRole('ROLE_EVP')");
    }
}
```

To learn more about custom filter click [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter).

Next, for this one

```
<bean id="filterEntryPoint" 
  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
<property name="loginFormUrl">
    <value>https://companyLogin.com</value>
</property>
<property name="forceHttps">
    <value>false</value>
</property>
```

You need to define a bean

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .addFilterBefore(new MyCustomFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') and hasRole('ROLE_EVP')");

    //defined bean
    @Bean
    public LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint filterEntryPoint() {
        LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("https://companyLogin.com");
        entryPoint.setForceHttps(false);

        return entryPoint;
    }
}
```

I think that's all.